# Getting images from Facebook to windows phone

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to integrate a certain Facebook page to my windows phone application. All I want is to get the images posted by the page admin and display it in the application. Is this possible to implement on the windows phone?
Thank You

Comment: Hi, have you met google ?

Comment: I searched it on Google and I did not find any results, hence question on stackoverflow :)